# Azure Websites CPU %

Tags: azure

Does anyone know of a way to access the Azure Websites CPU % utilization for a standard instance?

Up until recently it didn't much matter (like many questions here were answered with). You knew how many seconds and that was good enough. However, now with auto-scale, based on CPU % utilization, it would be wise to know what one's websites service is normally running, yet this isn't available anywhere that I can find.

Considering that CPU utilization is how they're auto-scaling, this data must be somewhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is now available in the new portal.

Answer (score -1):

it sounds like you are interested in monitoring the CPU usage of your instances. You could use the performance counter ***"% Processor Time"*** for this purpose. 
This blog post contains detailed instructions on how to configure and collect performance counter data:
http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/net/common-tasks/performance-profiling/

Comment: He's asking about Azure Websites.  Azure Diagnostics & Performance counters are not available with Azure Websites, only Webroles